# How to return the integer with the lowest value that occurs the most frequently in an array?

Tags: c

I managed to write code to return which number occurs the most but when multiple numbers occur the same amount of times I need to return the one with the lowest value.

```
int getFreq(int arg) {

    int tmp;
    int storage[10] = { 0 };
    int maxDigit = -1;
    int maxfreq = -1;

    tmp = (arg < 0) ? -arg : arg;

    do {

        storage[tmp % 10]++;

        if (storage[tmp % 10] > maxDigit) {

            maxDigit = storage[tmp % 10];
            maxFreq = tmp % 10;

        }

        tmp /= 10;

    } while (tmp != 0);

    return maxFreq;
}
```

Comment: Fine, you showed your code. You could remove some empty lines, but otherwise it is nicely formatted. What was the question?

Comment: The question was posted above. I am looking for a way to return the digit with the lowest value if multiple digits occur the same amount of times. For example, if the number is 1100 it should return 0 instead of 1 as the original code is doing right now.

Comment: Note: your code will fail if `arg` == `INT_MIN` for 2s complement representation.

Comment: So, instead of calculating which digit occurs most frequently as you go, just keep a record of the most frequent number of appearances, and then at the end cycle through the array of counts, choosing the first one that matches the most frequent number of appearances.  Note you'll have problems on most machines if your user gives you `-2147483648` (which is `INT_MIN` if you have 32-bit `int`, which is very common but not automatic everywhere) to process as a number.

Comment: Sorry, but you are lacking a clear problem statement. Do not write this in a comment, but edit your question. Please take the [tour].

Comment: Fixed, my apologies.

Comment: Nope, your edit just shows what **you** are supposed to do. What exactly is your problem hindering you to accomplish this? Do you have a **specific** question or are you really asking us to write your code?

Comment: Something like: `if ((storage[tmp % 10] > maxDigit) || (storage[tmp % 10] == maxDigit && (tmp %10 < maxFreq)))`? That is, just add a condition to check for exactly how you described the requirement.

Comment: Note: The usages of `maxDigit` and `maxFreq` are missleading imo. they should be swapped: `maxDigit` should be the digit with the maximum frequency, while `maxFreq` would be the frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tinkered with your function, and separated the statistic gathering from its analysis, to make it easy to find the most frequent, but lowest, number. The 6 and 7 both occur twice. The 7's bracket the 6's in the number presented, but the function returns 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getFreq(int arg) {
    int tmp;
    int storage[10] = { 0 };
    int maxFreq = -1;
    int digit = 0;

    tmp = (arg < 0) ? -arg : arg;
    do {
        storage[tmp % 10]++;
        tmp /= 10;
    } while (tmp);

    for (tmp=9; tmp>=0; tmp--) {
        if (storage[tmp] >= maxFreq) {
            digit = tmp;
            maxFreq = storage[tmp];
        }
    }
    return digit;
}

int main(void)
{
    int val = 17266375;
    printf("Most frequent (lowest) from %d = %d\n", val, getFreq(val));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Most frequent (lowest) from 17266375 = 6
```